# High Level Language to HDL

Tags: verilog, hdl

I need to convert a simple program (C or Java) to HDL (especially Verilog). However, I have no idea about this conversion.

Another problem is that the resulting code must be gate level. Now, This idea does not seem possible for me. I have not much expeience so I need some help.

I searched for these problems but I could not find anything helpful. Is there any tutorial about these topic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Quick googling for "C to Verilog" produces: http://c-to-verilog.com/ ; there are various tools to do this, but they only work for carefully constructed programs and not very well at that.

Comment: 1. Consider the capabilities of your hardware. 2. Consider the functions performed by your program. 3. Find a way to perform the functions using the capabilities. 4. Write Verilog to describe that. *Key point*: Writing synthesizable Verilog means starting out by thinking about the capabilities of the hardware you have available.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a general automated way to do what you're asking for. HDL programming is fundamentally different from sequential programming. You will almost certainly need to create a new HDL project and manually code it to perform the same function as the C project you're starting with.

Comment: I need a start point. For example, simple examples would be good. I could not find anything.

Comment: You mean, examples of how to code in an HDL for (I assume) an FPGA? It's been a while, but I'd start with the docs for the FPGA you have in mind. I'd expect them to have some examples.

Comment: It can be anything I just need a start point. If you add something, It would be great. Thanks.